# Issues in using ng-grid - performance, responsiveness

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid to display data on my page. There are 2 grids on the page, but I am facing these issues:

1. Grid is not responsive, it has fixed height and width.
2. Browser hangs momentarily before grid is rendered. I do not know this issue is with ng-grid or that I am putting lot of data in controller which is degrading performance. This is visible bad when the grid loads first time. Performance remains fine when I change data set and grid renders again.

Any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CSS is not loaded properly.

Browser hang may be of many reasons.

May be a long wait for the data from back-end(if sync call is sent).

Recursion of a loop with no valid data.

Dependency of the grid on the other grid/data-source which's not available when rendering.

Comment: Yep I think it needs thorough profiling, but I am wondering if it could be issue with ng-grid as performance if fine if I remove grids.

Comment: I have used ng-grid in few place, and switched to basic table for some requirement reasons, not faced issues with ng-grid. It was working fine. Many people are working into it, but no one has complained like this. Looks like you got some dependency issue with the ng-grid. As it also has dependency on jquery.